# vmware unlocker error: "file not found - darwin*.*"

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation

I Have vmware workstation 14 pro and macOS Unlocker 3,
When I run unlocker, I get this error:

```
    main()
  File "gettools.py", line 91, in main
    response = urlopen(url)
  File "urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
  File "urllib2.py", line 435, in open
  File "urllib2.py", line 548, in http_response
  File "urllib2.py", line 467, in error
  File "urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
  File "urllib2.py", line 654, in http_error_302
  File "urllib2.py", line 435, in open
  File "urllib2.py", line 548, in http_response
  File "urllib2.py", line 473, in error
  File "urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
  File "urllib2.py", line 556, in http_error_default
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
[8160] Failed to execute script gettools
File not found - darwin*.*
0 File(s) copied
```

I Have tried this with many different versions of vmware and vmware unlocker, but all of them saying this error. and I Have searched for this error, please help me!

Comment: I could not fix that, then I deleted that and installed "VirtualBox".

Answer (score 8):

Some unlockers doesn't work well. Try [this](https://github.com/paolo-projects/unlocker) unlocker

Comment: This works for the latest VMware Workstation 15.5.3 and 15.5.6

Comment: Thanks for correct answer.

Comment: I have 16 and this unlocker doesn't fix the lovely bootloop

Answer (score 0):

For me I  just install python and then run Unlocker now it works fine
Don't know why

Answer (score 0):

Basically it is trying to get the wrong url, as folders structure changed to support universal build instead of special build for x86.

This is how I fixed for me.

Edit file:
\VMwareUnlocker3.0.4\gettools.py

Line 132 changed it from:
urlcoretar = url + lastVersion + '/' + **ARCH** + '/core/com.vmware.fusion.zip.tar'
to:
urlcoretar = url + lastVersion + '**/universal**/core/com.vmware.fusion.zip.tar'

Then had to change also couple more lines (148,149,153,154) by adding (**x86_x64**) to the path
cdszip.extract('payload/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Library/isoimages/**x86_x64**/darwin.iso', path=convertpath(dest + '/tools/'))
cdszip.extract('payload/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Library/isoimages/**x86_x64**/darwinPre15.iso', path=convertpath(dest + '/tools/'))
shutil.move(convertpath(dest + '/tools/payload/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Library/isoimages/**x86_x64**/darwin.iso'), convertpath(dest + '/tools/darwin.iso'))
shutil.move(convertpath(dest + '/tools/payload/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Library/isoimages/**x86_x64**/darwinPre15.iso'), convertpath(dest + '/tools/darwinPre15.iso'))